# O índice e o comprimento devem se referir a um local dentro da sequencia

Tags: vb.net

Preciso quebrar uma variável para pegar o valor do banco de dados. Hoje o meu retorno completo seria "2017-09-15T14:01:46" Eu preciso apenas de 2017-09-15 e 14:01, tentei fazer

.Substring(0,10) para a data e funcionou, já para a hora tentei Substring(11,16) e ocorre o erro que está no titulo da pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não consegue fazer algo assim?

```
data.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM")
```